# checking Network Status while running the app in android

Tags: android, connectivity

I am streaming a video by using some url. Here, when i started the application I have checked the network status, or when i came to onResume state, i checked the Network status. But , while streaming is playing, If any cause net work will fail.. How can i check the status of the Network.
 Here i am using this code for check the status..

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    boolean state = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork =
        cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifiNetwork != null) {
                state=wifiNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
             }

        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork =
        cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (mobileNetwork != null) {
            state=mobileNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            state=activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }

        return state;
  }
```

from oncreate and orResume method, i was calling this method.. But how can i find the status of Network while running the app.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your `Activity`, that will receive the connectivity change broadcast. So inside the `onReceive()` method, that will be triggered when there will be a change in your connectivity, you will have to take actions :

```
    BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //take actions
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver,
        new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
```

You will also need to add the following permission to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```